# jquery animate only fires once with keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Trying to get the p element to move 2D galactica style with awsd keys. 
The keys work, just only once without having to refresh the page.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Moving with arrows</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery (console.log was obviously just to learn the keycodes)

```
var main = function () {

$("body").on("keypress", function (event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);

    if (event.keyCode === 97) {
        $("p").animate({right: "5px"});
    }
    else if (event.keyCode === 100) {
        $("p").animate({left: "5px"});
    }
    else if (event.keyCode === 119) {
        $("p").animate({bottom: "5px"});
    }
    else if (event.keyCode === 115) {
        $("p").animate({top: "5px"});
    }
});
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

The Style

```
body {
background: black;
width: 750px;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

p {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 50%;
color: white;
background: grey;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've set for instance `top` to `5px` what do you expect should happen the next time you hit the button? You have to increment, and in jQuery you can use `+=` and `-=` to do that

```
$("body").on("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 97) {
        $("p").animate({
            left: "-=5px"
        });
    } else if (event.keyCode === 100) {
        $("p").animate({
            left: "+=5px"
        });
    } else if (event.keyCode === 119) {
        $("p").animate({
            top: "-=5px"
        });
    } else if (event.keyCode === 115) {
        $("p").animate({
            top: "+=5px"
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7x8szdsa/)

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to fiddle. :)